# Show Lipschitz continuity of ODE solution with respect to initial condition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am working on the nonlinear pendulum differential equation given by

$$
\theta'' = -g\sin \theta.
$$

Let $t \geq 0$ be fix, I define for $\theta_0 \in (-\frac\pi2, \frac\pi2)$ a mapping $S$ by

$$
S(\theta_0) = \theta(t; \theta_0),
$$

where $\theta(t; \theta_0)$ is the solution of the initial value problem for the ODE defined above with initial conditions $\theta'(0) = 0$ and $ \theta(0) = \theta_0$.

I believe the mapping $S$ is Lipschitz continuous, but is it true? If yes, how could I prove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading through some old lecture notes, it seems that the derivative of $S$ is as many times continuously differentiable as the RHS of the problem. (I can't link anything here unfortunately)

By changing $(-\frac\pi2, \frac\pi2)$ to $[-\frac\pi2, \frac\pi2]$, $S$ is now a $C^1$ function on a compact interval, thus Lipschitz continuous.

Answer (score 0):

Multiplying your equation by $\theta'$ gives
$\theta'\theta''=-g\theta'\sin\theta$ or

$\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{1}{2}\theta'^2-g\cos\theta\right)=0\Rightarrow\frac{1}{2}\theta'^2-g\cos\theta=c$

$\theta' = \pm\sqrt{2(c+g\cos\theta)}$

Every function that has a bounded derivative is Lipshitz continuous. This would be where I would start the proof. Notice that the square root is bounded $\forall\,\theta$.

Comment: Hi, I had the same idea and same result for $\theta’$, but this doesn’t work. The theorem you’ve stated is right, but this would tell us that the function $t \mapsto \theta(t; \theta_0)$ is Lipschitz continuous, which is not what i want. To use this theorem, I would need to know the derivative of $S$ wrt. $\theta_0$, which is very different, and unknown to me at least. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Using your initial conditions at the above stage gives $c=-g\cos\theta_0$ factor out $\sqrt{2g}$, separate variables and set up the integral. We get $\int_{\theta_0}^\theta\frac{d\phi}{\sqrt{\cos\phi-\cos\theta_0}}=\pm\sqrt{2g}t$. The derivative of the integral WRT $\theta_0$ on the left could be worked out with the fundamental theorem of calculus? All of your $\theta_0$ dependence is there.

Comment: I see the singularity in my attempt and the elliptic integral will make using the definition of Lipshitz continuity difficult i think: $|S(\theta_1)-S(\theta_0)|<k|\theta_1-\theta_0|$ for $\theta\in(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$

Comment: I found a paper discussing this topic here: http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~lebovitz/Eodesbook/reg.pdf On page 143  the discussion is on continuous dependence and there is a proof of continuity if RHS is Lipshitz. He then goes on to discuss differentiability of the solutions WRT the initial conditions. Hope this helps.